# Would initializing a variable in (e.g) a loop be less efficient than just using one already defined?

Tags: c++

So guys I am having a bit of trouble understanding how memory is allocated on the stack. First let me show you the code I am going to talk about:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    
    int testing{};
    for (int i{}; i < 15; ++i) {
        int j{i};
        testing = j;
    }
    std::cout << testing << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

So here what I am having trouble understanding is how memory allocation happens on the stack, or what happens behind the scenes when defining/initializing a variable on the stack. I am unsure of which one would be considered more efficient, either the code above or the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int testing{};
    int j{};
    for (int i{}; i < 15; ++i) {
        j = i;
        testing = j;
    }
    std::cout << testing << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the difference is that I have intialized my variable once, and the other times I am just accessing that variable and changing its value, now I am unsure if that makes it more efficient or not (taking in mind this is a very simple program but imagine this in a much larger and costlier example) since what I think is that when you define/initialize a variable it allocates memory for that variable pre-execution and what we are doing in example-2 is just accessing that already allocated memory, whereas in example-1, I keep redefining that variable, wouldn't that keep on alloacting and deallocating memory as the variable goes out of scope? Please could someone explain this for me? I am extremely confused since if I remembered correctly and it does allocate contiguous memory for the program pre-execution isn't the first example allocating memory at run time, which confuses me because I associate that with dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: I'd imagine a decent compiler would optimize away the difference, but I'm curious to see the answers. Nice question!

Comment: I guess some C++ implementations would run the first snippet faster, others the second one, (many) others they would optimize the difference away. In your question you seem to imply there is only one C++ implementation, that runs code in a certain way, and no deviation is possible. This is not the case. Try to compile your code on some site like godbolt.org where you can observe the resulting assembly, and experiment with different compilers / optimization levels.

Comment: There's guaranteed to be no difference between these versions. In fact, with any modern compiler and optimizations turned on, the only code that will be generated is to print `14`.

Comment: Here are [both version on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/oWMxzc). They produce identical assembly code with gcc or clang. Choose the version that is clearer to you or better expresses your intent. Don't "optimize" too early, better code comes from better algorithms and data structures.

Comment: To go along with @Blastfurnace 's comment, [this link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d6oETK) shows the assembly on GCC, clang, and MSVC *with optimizations disabled*.  We can see that even with no optimizations, GCC and clang produce almost exactly the same assembly, and MSVC is at least very close between the two implementations.

Comment: It's worth noting that the result would be _very_ different if `j` were a `std::string` instead of a primitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trivial type you don't take the address of has no real existence.

Compilers will extract side effects, and ignore you copying it around.

Compilers don't have to, but they are also free to do a+b as a loop.

When you do a debug build it will sometimes brainlessly make extra steps and copies to allow you to create pointless intermediate values; this is to permit things like data breakpoints to work easier.

Comment: Effectively, a typical DEBUG build will generate code for each C++ instruction in the original order as otherwise, it s very difficult to follow the program while debugging.

Comment: @Phil1970 And, it has to create some semi-stable memory location for (almost) all variables, so you can inspect them; note that elision can make this a bit strange, but even then the object exists, it just has a shared identity.